# How to pass arguments to a function dynamically?

Tags: c, function

I have a function like

```
fun(){
    y=true;
    p=false;
    n=false;
    r=true;
    flag=true;  
}
```

And I have another function

```
call-parameters(){
}
```

I need to pass only true values to call-parameters function as arguments. How can I achieve that?

Comment: generally it would be like: 
`function(param1, param2){
param1 = smth;
param2 = smth;
}`
call for that function: 
`function(x, y);`
Provide more details in your question.

Comment: thank you Jane Doe , I want it in c language..the first function fun() is not the same all the time. i need every time that whatever the value is true ,that should be passed as an argument to call-parameters() function.

Answer (score 1):

Make an array of variables which have true values.Pass this array to to your function `call-parameters(){
}` then you can extract variable from array.